# Is it possible to use angular localization in an Ionic application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, localization, ngx-translate

I've configured angular localizacion (through configuration of the file `angular.json`) in an application that in fact is an Ionic application.

The problem is that now I get the following error when I try to run `capacitor sync`:

```
[capacitor] [error] The web assets directory (./www) must contain an index.html file.
```

This is because the application now has two directories, one per translated version (one called `en` for english and another one `es` for spanish).

Should I have used ngx-translate instead?

Comment: What have I discovered so far: [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config) are the config options for capacitor, and it allows you to configure many things but no option for i18n, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use it with Angular's i18n, but you need to have all the build files generated copied to your www folder. And you need a separate index.html to make it work.

#### Possible Workaround

I haven't tested myself yet. In theory, you could make Angular's i18n work by:

1. Create an index.html that routes the user to the correct locale, In this [github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3912#issuecomment-1272498658), I found a nice example.
2. Copy this index.html to root of the www folder, before syncing with the capacitor. You might use a script with [ionic's before build hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration)

##### Folder Structure

```
/www
--/en
--/fr
--index.html // => Copied by us
```

#### Trade-offs

- [+] With Angular's i18n, you don't need to worry about missing translations in runtime. The performance also should be slightly better since we don't need to bind any localization variable to memory.
- [-] You need to include all the generated folders for each locale, which might consume extra space per each additional locale. In our case, it was an additional 3mb, which was negligible.
- [-] Each time a language changes, you need to reboot the angular application and navigate to the root of the other locale.

#### Separate Builds with One Locale

If you don't need runtime language changing, For example, you only want to include the English language in this app.

1. Make the `baseHref` the desired language to '/',
2. Update capacitor.config's webdir property to: 'www/'

angular.json

```
      ...
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "tr",
        "locales": {
          "en-US": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.en-US.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
```

capacitor.config.ts

```
  config = {
    ...
    webDir: "www/en-US",
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I left this theme of the localization abandoned, but this insight is interesting. Mainly because I was decided to use angular internationalization. Excelente analysis of the tradeoffs, by the way